# How to open default sms app in Lollipop andorid

Tags: android, sms, android-5.0-lollipop

When user click on a button default sms app should open and I am also supplying the message to whom I am sending the number but not being able to do that below is the code that I am using right now.

```
private void sendSMS(String _Mobile_Number) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // At least KitKat
    {
        String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context); // Need to change the build to API 19

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text to send");
     //   sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + _Mobile_Number));
        if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)// Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose
        // any app that support this intent.
        {
            sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
        }
        context.startActivity(sendIntent);

    } else // For early versions, do what worked for you before.
    {
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", _Mobile_Number);
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
        context.startActivity(smsIntent);
    }
}
```

when I use below line it give me exception.

```
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + _Mobile_Number));

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x1 pkg=com.google.android.talk (has clip) (has extras) }
```

if I do not use that line then my default app opens but it show me the list of contacts. when I select one contact the in the text are I see the text that I have written "text to send". But I don't  want this

What I want is when I click the button my default app open and in the contact  text box my provided number should be there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version

```
Uri smsUri = Uri.parse("tel:123456");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, smsUri);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "sms text");
intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send sms via:"));
```

Comment: what it dose is it show send sms via: only in a white rectangle background

Answer (score 0):

```
 String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
 Uri _uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + _Mobile_Number);
 Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, _uri);
 sendIntent.putExtra("address",_Mobile_Number);
 sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text to send");
 sendIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
 sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
 startActivity(sendIntent);
```

[image: Screenshot from Nexus 5, Lollypop - 5.1.0]

Comment: no help :( . it gives me exception that android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxxx flg=0x1 pkg=com.google.android.talk (has clip) (has extras) }

Comment: You tried in lollypop is it? It worked on kitkat for me though

Comment: i have tried it on kitkat it works but have any idea about lolypop ?

Comment: havent tried on Lollypop. My laptop is not in a mood to cooperate me to work on Android Studio now :P Will try so tomorow at office. Sory abt that.

Comment: I am afraid. It does work for me on lollypop.. I tried it yesterday itself . I just cross checked it